# Finding highest and lowest value of field for all children

Tags: mule, dataweave

1)
I want to extract the Id with the lowest value and the Id with the highest value from an array of items.

2)
When I have the 2 Id's I want to compare them against a static value e.g. '23'

3) ***(This is my problem)***
I thought about putting all the Id's into an array, and then sort the array and then extract the highest and lowest values by their index in the array [0] for the lowest Id and [-1] for the highest Id.

4)
Last I will do the comparison,
*(The field staticId is = '23')*

```
fun isIdBetween(lowestId, highestId, staticId) =
    if(staticId >= lowestId and staticId <= highestId)
        true
    else
        false
```

And put the result into a variable,

```
var result = isIdBetween(lowestId, highestId, staticId)
```

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Level1
    xmlns:ns="aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd">
    <Level2>
        <Level3>
            <Id>17</Id>
        </Level3>
        <Level3>
            <Id>219</Id>
        </Level3>
        <Level3>
            <Id>33</Id>
        </Level3>
    </Level2>
</ns:Level1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what is your problem your solution looks ok to me

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var ids = payload.Level1.Level2.*Level3.Id orderBy (idValue) -> idValue

fun isIdBetween(lowestId, highestId, staticId) =
    if(staticId >= lowestId and staticId <= highestId)
        true
    else
        false

var threshold = 23        
---
isIdBetween(ids[0],ids[1], threshold)
```

The dot selector will select the value of the first node that matches that label and the multivalue selector (.*) will select the value of all the nodes that matches that label. So basically payload.Level1.Level2.*Level3.Id returns an array with all the Id values. http://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-selectors . Then I only needed to sort it.

Comment: Hi Machaval.

It works, thank you.

I just dont completely understand this line: I can see what it does, but I dont understand how it does it.

var ids = payload.Level1.Level2.*Level3.Id orderBy (idValue) -> idValue

Do you perhaps have a link or any advise to how I can study DataWeave more in-depth?

Comment: Sure basically the dot selector will select the value of the first node that matches that label and the multivalue selector (.*) will select the value of all the nodes that matches that label. So basically `payload.Level1.Level2.*Level3.Id` returns an array with all the Id values. For more info visit . https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-selectors . Then I only needed to sort it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use min/max functions to get the min and max values.

And you can do a simple compare to find the range, just like you suggested:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = [17,219,33]
var static = 23
---
min(data) <= static and static <= max(data)
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan.

My main issue was item 3 in the list, and that one I could not solve without help.